# Save feature in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, save, flash-cs5

I'm currently developing a project manager in AS3 and I want to save them into files. I found this tutorial (http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/?p=1297) to create and read my own file types, but its using AIR.

I want to put some instances inside it too, because I need to know how the objects are positioning in my Main MovieClip.

Is it possible to do in AS3/Flash CS5?

Thanks!

EDIT: **I found XML type**. Can I write instances into XML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. The shared object provided by flash allows you to store data on the user's pc. Have a look at this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Comment: Thanks. I found XML type, and its maybe what I want. Can I write instances (with all of its properties) into them?

Comment: That should work if I'm not mistaken, but I have never tried it. Have a look at this: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashSharedObject/index.html

Comment: If you use a XML-object, remember that permission has to be given and not a lot of users will allow that... The shared object is created for this purpose and therefore recommended here.

Comment: But I want to store recently created file (SharedObject or XML) into a remote database, so maybe XML works better. What is your opinion?

Comment: In that case XML will probably work better yes... but I don't really have experience in that.